# IOS: Can't authenticate my JabberID with XMPP Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmppframework

I just followed this tutorial here (http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-xmpp-setup--mobile-7190) but I'm having a hard time to make the app work.

I'm connecting to a local XMPP server (Ejabberd 2.1.8) with XMPPFramework 3.5 (since the tutorial is kind of old I decided to use a previous release), I can't see any contacts but the app seems to run fine until it reaches the last line of this method:

```
- (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender {

    // connection to the server successful
    isOpen = YES;
    NSError *error = nil;

    [ [self xmppStream] authenticateWithPassword:password error:&error ];

}
```

Here's the error:

```
2014-04-21 18:16:36.485 JabberClient[3295:207] -[JabberClientAppDelegate xmppStream]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c3fd30
2014-04-21 18:16:36.486 JabberClient[3295:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[JabberClientAppDelegate xmppStream]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c3fd30'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c64052 0x1f36d0a 0x1c65ced 0x1bcaf00 0x1bcace2 0x2da2 0x1bca51d 0x1bca437 0x1bf549a 0x6f13e 0x1a7f445 0x1a814f0 0x1b9b833 0x1b9adb4 0x1b9accb 0x2154879 0x215493e 0x876a9b 0x265d 0x25d5)
terminate called throwing an exceptionCurrent language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb)
```

I can see that Ejabberd is receiving connections, but I guess it won't let me render the contacts list until the user is authenticated:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 2014-04-21 18:16:36 ===
I(<0.383.0>:ejabberd_listener:281) : (#Port<0.495>) Accepted connection {{127,0,0,1},51937} -> {{127,0,0,1},5222}
```

I couldn't find any resources to point me in the right direction, any ideas?

**-- UPDATE**

This is the class where this code is executing:

```
@interface JabberClientAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
        UIWindow *window;
        JabberClientViewController *viewController;
        XMPPStream *xmppStream;     
        NSString *password;
        BOOL isOpen;

    __weak NSObject  *_chatDelegate;
    __weak NSObject  *_messageDelegate;
}
```

Comment: Is that code in your app delegate? does it have a property named xmppStream. Probably switching `[self xmppStream]` to `sender` will let you continue, but you'll have problems later on. Let me know which class is that and whether it has a xmppStream property, then I can help you more

Comment: Yes, it is the app delegate class. I've decided to "Reset the content and settings" of the simulator and now this method is no longer called... still can't see the list of contacts from my local XMPP server. Would you have a STTCPW project clearly illustrating operations like, connect, retrieve users, send msg to specific user, etc.?

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing I can share on the internet. For getting the contact list you should use the Roster extension and it will request the contact list after the stream is connected: `XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage *xmppRosterStorage = [[XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage alloc] initWithInMemoryStore]; XMPPRoster *xmppRoster = [[XMPPRoster alloc] initWithRosterStorage:xmppRosterStorage]; xmppRoster.autoFetchRoster = YES; [xmppRoster activate:_xmppStream];`

Comment: Cool! Yeah, I noticed that the blogger's code is using the Roster, the sample from the framework is also using it (https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/tree/master/Xcode/iPhoneXMPP) -- I was able to run the sample app and load the contacts so I guess I should try to check the discrepancies and take it from there... Thanks @Matias_R!!

Answer (score 1):

May be your problem is that xmppStream is getting **nil**. use the below custom code for XMPP.

**MessageManager.h**

```
//  Created by Deepak MK.
//  Copyright © 2015 mindShiftApps. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "XMPP.h"
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "XMPPFramework.h"
#import "XMPPMessageDeliveryReceipts.h"
#import "XMPPLastActivity.h"
#import "XMPPRosterMemoryStorage.h"
#import "XMPPRoomMemoryStorage.h"
#import "XMPPvCardCoreDataStorage.h"
#import "XMPPvCardTemp.h"
/**
 message manager class manage all message sequence.
 */
@interface MessageManager : NSObject
{

    XMPPStream                                  *xmppStream;

    NSString                                    *password;

    BOOL                                        isOpen;

    BOOL                                        isRegistering;

    id                                          _delgate;

    XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage                    *xmppRosterStorage;

    XMPPRoster                                           *xmppRoster;

    XMPPvCardCoreDataStorage* xmppvCardStorage;
    XMPPvCardTempModule*xmppvCardTempModule;



}

+ (MessageManager *) sharedMessageHandler;

/**
 The stream varible for connecting stream
 */

@property (nonatomic, readonly) XMPPStream          *xmppStream;

/**
 XMPPRoster  varible
 */
@property (nonatomic, strong,readonly) XMPPRoster *xmppRoster;

/**
 XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage  varible 
 */
@property (nonatomic, strong,readonly) XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage *xmppRosterStorage;

/**
 XMPPRoom  varible
 */
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly)  XMPPRoom *xmppRoom;


/**
 Setting of delegate
 @param delegate class delegate
 */
- (void) setdelegate:(id)delegate;

/**
 Return of delegate
 */
- (id)   delegate;

/**
 connecting stream of Xmpp server
 */

- (void) setupStream;

/**
 Connect user to Xmpp server
 @param jabberID    login user name
 @param myPassword  login password
 */
- (BOOL)connectWithUserId:(NSString*)jabberID withPassword:(NSString*)myPassword;

/**
 Connect user to Xmpp server
 @param userName    login user name
 @param myPassword  login password
 */
- (void) authenticateUserWIthUSerName:(NSString*)userName withPassword:(NSString*)myPassword;


/**
 disconnect user from Xmpp server
 */
- (void) disconnect;

/**
 changes the presence to online
 */
- (void) goOnline;

/**
 changes the presence to offline
 */
- (void) goOffline;

/**
 Register new user to xmpp server
 @param userName    new user name
 @param _password   new password
 @param EmailId     new email id
 */
- (void)registerStudentWithUserName:(NSString *)userName withPassword:(NSString *)_password withEmailId:(NSString *)EmailId;


/**
 send message to other user with content
 @param toAdress destination address
 @param content  content of message
 */
- (BOOL)sendMessageTo:(NSString*)toAdress withContents:(NSString*)content;



/**
 This method is used for sending subscribe invitation to user
 @param userID destination address
 */
- (void) sendSubscribeMessageToUser:(NSString*)userID;


/**
 This method is used for setting substate of presence
 @param subState substate of user
 */
- (void) presenceWithStubState:(NSString*)subState;


/**
 This method is used to create new room
 @param ChatRoomJID New room name
 */
- (void) setUpRoom:(NSString *)ChatRoomJID;


/**
 This method is used to destroyRoom
 */
- (void) destroyCreatedRoom;

/**
 This method is used to send message to group
 */
- (BOOL)sendGroupMessageWithBody:(NSString*)_body;



- (void) requestAllMesssage;

@end





/**
 Set of methods to be implemented to act as a restaurant patron
 */
@protocol MessageManagerDelegate <NSObject>

/**
 Methods to be get state of stream
 */
- (void) didGetStreamState:(BOOL)state;

/**
 Methods to be get state of Authentication
 */

- (void) didGetAuthenticationState:(BOOL)state;

/**
 Methods to be get state of registration
 */

- (void) didGetRegistrationState:(BOOL)state WithErrorMessage:(NSString*)errorMessage;

/**
 Methods to get recieved message
 */

- (void) didReceiveMessageWithBody:(NSString *) body;


/**
 Methods to get presence of other user
 */
- (void) didRecievePresence:(NSString*)state withUserName:(NSString*)userName WithSubState:(NSString*)subState;


/**
 Methods to get event of user joined room
 */
- (void) didCreatedOrJoinedRoomWithCreatedRoomName:(NSString*)_roomName;


- (void) didGetUserJoinedToRoomORLeaveRoomWithName:(NSString*)_userName WithPresence:(NSString*)presence;
@end
```

**MessageManager.m**

```
#import "MessageManager.h"

#import "DDLog.h"
#import "DDTTYLogger.h"
#import <CFNetwork/CFNetwork.h>
#if DEBUG
static const int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE;
#else
static const int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_INFO;
#endif


@interface MessageManager()


@end

static MessageManager *sharedMessageHandler = nil;

@implementation MessageManager

@synthesize xmppStream;
@synthesize xmppRoster;
@synthesize xmppRosterStorage;
@synthesize xmppRoom;

#pragma mark - self class Delegate
- (void) setdelegate:(id)delegate
{
    _delgate= delegate;
}
- (id)   delegate
{
    return _delgate;
}



#pragma  mark - custom Functions
+ (MessageManager *) sharedMessageHandler
{

    if (sharedMessageHandler == nil)
    {
        sharedMessageHandler = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
    }

    return sharedMessageHandler;
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {

    return [self sharedMessageHandler];
}

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {

    return self;
}


#pragma mark - connection setup Functions

/**
 This fuction is used to setup XMPP Stream
 */
- (void)setupStream
{

    // Setup xmpp stream
    //
    // The XMPPStream is the base class for all activity.
    // Everything else plugs into the xmppStream, such as modules/extensions and delegates.

    xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];
    [xmppStream setHostName:kBaseXMPPURL];
    [xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

}

/** 
 This fuction is used to Connect XMPP With userId and Password 
 */
- (BOOL)connectWithUserId:(NSString*)jabberID withPassword:(NSString*)myPassword
{

    [self setupStream];

    isRegistering=NO;

    if (![xmppStream isDisconnected]) {
        return YES;
    }


    if (jabberID == nil || myPassword == nil) {

        return NO;
    }

    [xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:jabberID]];
    password = myPassword;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![xmppStream connectWithTimeout:XMPPStreamTimeoutNone error:&error])
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                            message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Can't connect to server %@", [error localizedDescription]]
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];


        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}


- (void) authenticateUserWIthUSerName:(NSString*)userName withPassword:(NSString*)myPassword
{

    if ([xmppStream isConnected])
    {
        NSError*error =nil;
        [xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:userName]];
        [xmppStream authenticateWithPassword:myPassword error:&error];

    }
    else
    {
        [self connectWithUserId:userName withPassword:myPassword];
    }

}


#pragma mark ---Delegate of Connect
/**
 This fuction is called when stream is connected
 */
- (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender {

    isOpen = YES;
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSLog(@"Stream Connected");
    if (!isRegistering)
    {
        if([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(didGetStreamState:)])
        {
            [[self delegate]didGetStreamState:YES];
        }

        [xmppStream authenticateWithPassword:password error:&error];
    }
    else
    {
        [xmppStream registerWithPassword:password error:&error];
    }


}

/**
 This fuction is called when User is Authenticated
 */
- (void)xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender {

    [self goOnline];
    NSLog(@"Stream Authenticated");
    if([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(didGetAuthenticationState:)])
    {
        [[self delegate]didGetAuthenticationState:YES];
    }



    if ([xmppStream isAuthenticated]) {
        NSLog(@"authenticated");
        xmppvCardStorage = [[XMPPvCardCoreDataStorage alloc] initWithInMemoryStore];
        xmppvCardTempModule = [[XMPPvCardTempModule alloc] initWithvCardStorage:xmppvCardStorage];
        [xmppvCardTempModule activate:[self xmppStream]];
        [xmppvCardTempModule addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
        [xmppvCardTempModule fetchvCardTempForJID:[sender myJID] ignoreStorage:YES];
    }

}

- (void)xmppvCardTempModule:(XMPPvCardTempModule *)vCardTempModule didReceivevCardTemp:(XMPPvCardTemp *)vCardTemp forJID:(XMPPJID *)jid{


    NSLog(@"Delegate is called");
    XMPPvCardTemp *vCard = [xmppvCardStorage vCardTempForJID:jid xmppStream:xmppStream];
    NSLog(@"Stored card: %@",vCard);
    NSLog(@"%@", vCard.description);
    NSLog(@"%@", vCard.name);
    NSLog(@"%@", vCard.emailAddresses);
    NSLog(@"%@", vCard.formattedName);
    NSLog(@"%@", vCard.givenName);
    NSLog(@"%@", vCard.middleName);

}

/**
 This fuction is called when User is  not Authenticated
 */
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didNotAuthenticate:(NSXMLElement *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Not Authenticated");

    if([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(didGetAuthenticationState:)])
    {
        [[self delegate]didGetAuthenticationState:NO];
    }
}


#pragma mark - Stream disconnection

/**
 This fuction is used to disconnet user
 */
- (void)disconnect
{
    [self goOffline];
    [xmppStream disconnect];
}

#pragma mark ---Delegate of disconnect
/**
 This fuction is called when stream is disConnected
 */
- (void)xmppStreamDidDisconnect:(XMPPStream *)sender withError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Stream Disconnected");
    if([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(didGetStreamState:)])
    {
        [[self delegate]didGetStreamState:NO];
    }
}




#pragma mark - setting presence

/** 
 This fuction is used change the presence to online 
 */
- (void)goOnline
{
    XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presence];
    [xmppStream sendElement:presence];
}

/**
 This fuction is used change the presence to Ofline 
 */
- (void)goOffline
{
    XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presenceWithType:@"unavailable"];
    [xmppStream sendElement:presence];
}


/**
 This fuction is used change the presence substate
 */
- (void) presenceWithStubState:(NSString*)subState
{
    XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presence];// type="available" is implicit

    NSXMLElement *status = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"status"];
    [status setStringValue:subState];
    [presence addChild:status];

    [xmppStream sendElement:presence];
}

/**
 This fuction is called when other user state is changed
 */
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceivePresence:(XMPPPresence *)presence
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@ - %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD, [presence fromStr]);


    NSString *presenceType = [presence type];            // online/offline
    NSString *myUsername = [[sender myJID] user];
    NSString *presenceFromUser = [[presence from] user];
    NSString* presenceState= [presence status];

    NSLog(@"%@  is %@ state %@",presenceFromUser,presenceType,presenceState);

    if (![presenceFromUser isEqualToString:myUsername])
    {

        if ([presenceType isEqualToString:@"available"])
        {
            if([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(didRecievePresence:withUserName:WithSubState:)])
            {
                [[self delegate] didRecievePresence:presenceType withUserName:presenceFromUser WithSubState:presenceState];
            }

        }

        else if  ([presenceType isEqualToString:@"unavailable"]) {

             if([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(didRecievePresence:withUserName:WithSubState:)])
             {
                 [[self delegate] didRecievePresence:presenceType withUserName:presenceFromUser WithSubState:presenceState];
             }

        }
        else if  ([presenceType isEqualToString:@"subscribe"])
        {

            [xmppRoster subscribePresenceToUser:[presence from]];
            [self goOnline];
        }
        else if  ([presenceType isEqualToString:@"subscribed"])
        {
            [xmppRoster subscribePresenceToUser:[presence from]];
        }

    }
    if (xmppRoom)
    {
        [xmppRoom fetchMembersList];
    }


}

#pragma mark - subscription
- (void) sendSubscribeMessageToUser:(NSString*)userID
{
    XMPPJID* jbid=  [XMPPJID jidWithString:userID];
    XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presenceWithType:@"subscribe" to:jbid];
    [xmppStream sendElement:presence];
}


#pragma mark - XMPP delegates
/**
 This fuction is called when new IQ is received 
 */
- (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq {

    return NO;

}



#pragma mark - RegistrationFunction

/**
 This fuction is user to retister new user
   if stream is connected the it will directly call registeration function
    otherwise it will connect stream and then call registeration process 
 */

- (void)registerStudentWithUserName:(NSString *)userName withPassword:(NSString *)_password withEmailId:(NSString *)EmailId
{

    if (xmppStream==nil)
    {
        [self setupStream];
    }


    [xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:userName]];
    NSLog(@"Attempting registration for username %@",xmppStream.myJID.bare);
    password=_password;
    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success;

    if(![ xmppStream isConnected])
    {
         success = [[self xmppStream] connectWithTimeout:XMPPStreamTimeoutNone error:&error];
        isRegistering=YES;
    }
    else
    {
        success = [[self xmppStream] registerWithPassword:_password error:&error];
    }

    if (success)
    {
        NSLog(@"succeed ");
        isRegistering=YES;
    }
    else
    {
        if([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(didGetRegistrationState:WithErrorMessage:)])
        {
            [[self delegate]didGetRegistrationState:YES WithErrorMessage:@"Stream not connected"];
        }
    }

}

#pragma mark ---delegates of registrtaion


/**
 This fuction is called when new user is registered 
 */
- (void)xmppStreamDidRegister:(XMPPStream *)sender{




    if([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(didGetRegistrationState:WithErrorMessage:)])
    {
        [[self delegate]didGetRegistrationState:YES WithErrorMessage:@"Registration with XMPP Successful!"];
    }


}


/**
 This fuction is called when registeration process failed 
 */
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didNotRegister:(NSXMLElement *)error{

//    DDXMLElement *errorXML = [error elementForName:@"error"];
//    NSString *errorCode  = [[errorXML attributeForName:@"code"] stringValue];

//    NSString *regError = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ERROR :- %@",error.description];
//    
//    
//    if([errorCode isEqualToString:@"409"])
//    {
//        regError=@"Username Already Exists!";
//    }
//    else
//    {
//        regError= @"Server not connected";
//    }
    if([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(didGetRegistrationState:WithErrorMessage:)])
    {
        [[self delegate]didGetRegistrationState:NO WithErrorMessage:@"Username Already Exists!"];
    }

}



#pragma mark - send  and recieve message
/**
 This fuction is used to send message to other user with contents of body
 */



//-(void)sendMessageTo:(NSString*)toAdress withContents:(NSString*)messageStr
//{
//    
//    
//    if([messageStr length]> 0)
//    {
//        
//        NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
//        [body setStringValue:messageStr];
//        
//        NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
//        [message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
//        [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:toAdress];
//        [message addChild:body];
//        
//        [self.xmppStream sendElement:message];
//    }
//}



- (BOOL)sendMessageTo:(NSString*)toAdress withContents:(NSString*)content
{

    if([content length]> 0)
    {

        NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
        [body setStringValue:content];

        NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
        [message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
        [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:toAdress];
        [message addChild:body];

        [self.xmppStream sendElement:message];
    }
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark  recieve message
/**
 This fuction is called when new message arrived
 */

- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);

    // A simple example of inbound message handling.
    if ([message body])
    {
        NSString *body = [[message elementForName:@"body"] stringValue];
        if([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(didReceiveMessageWithBody:)])
        {
            [[self delegate] didReceiveMessageWithBody:body];
        }

    }
}



#pragma mark - create new room

/**
 This fuction is used to setup room with roomId
 */
-(void)setUpRoom:(NSString *)ChatRoomJID
{
    if (!ChatRoomJID)
    {
        return;
    }
    // Configure xmppRoom
    XMPPRoomMemoryStorage *roomMemoryStorage = [[XMPPRoomMemoryStorage alloc] init];

    XMPPJID *roomJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:ChatRoomJID];

    xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:roomMemoryStorage jid:roomJID dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    [xmppRoom activate:xmppStream];
    [xmppRoom addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    NSXMLElement *history = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"history"];
    [history addAttributeWithName:@" maxchars" stringValue:@"0"];
    [xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:xmppStream.myJID.user
                            history:history
                           password:nil];


    [self performSelector:@selector(ConfigureNewRoom:) withObject:nil afterDelay:4];

}

/**
 This fuction is used configure new
 */
- (void)ConfigureNewRoom:(id)sender
{
    [xmppRoom configureRoomUsingOptions:nil];
    [xmppRoom fetchConfigurationForm];
    [xmppRoom fetchBanList];
    [xmppRoom fetchMembersList];
    [xmppRoom fetchModeratorsList];

}

/**
 This fuction is called when new room is created
 */
- (void)xmppRoomDidCreate:(XMPPRoom *)sender
{
    DDLogInfo(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);

    // I am inviting friends after room is created


}

/**
 This fuction is called when user joined room
 */
- (void)xmppRoomDidJoin:(XMPPRoom *)sender
{
    [sender fetchMembersList];
    [sender fetchConfigurationForm];
    [self requestAllMesssage];
    DDLogInfo(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);
    if([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(didCreatedOrJoinedRoomWithCreatedRoomName:)])
    {
        [[self delegate] didCreatedOrJoinedRoomWithCreatedRoomName:sender.myRoomJID.bare];
    }

}

- (void)xmppRoom:(XMPPRoom *)sender didFetchMembersList:(NSArray *)items
{

}

- (void)xmppRoom:(XMPPRoom *)sender occupantDidJoin:(XMPPJID *)occupantJID withPresence:(XMPPPresence *)presence
{
    if([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(didGetUserJoinedToRoomORLeaveRoomWithName:WithPresence:)])
    {
//        id details =occupantJID;
//        NSString* string = (NSString*)details;
         [[self delegate] didGetUserJoinedToRoomORLeaveRoomWithName:[occupantJID resource] WithPresence:[presence type]];
    }

}
- (void)xmppRoom:(XMPPRoom *)sender occupantDidLeave:(XMPPJID *)occupantJID withPresence:(XMPPPresence *)presence
{
    if([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(didGetUserJoinedToRoomORLeaveRoomWithName:WithPresence:)])
    {
        [[self delegate] didGetUserJoinedToRoomORLeaveRoomWithName:[occupantJID resource] WithPresence:[presence type]];
    }
}
- (void)xmppRoom:(XMPPRoom *)sender occupantDidUpdate:(XMPPJID *)occupantJID withPresence:(XMPPPresence *)presence
{
    if([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(didGetUserJoinedToRoomORLeaveRoomWithName:WithPresence:)])
    {
        [[self delegate] didGetUserJoinedToRoomORLeaveRoomWithName:[occupantJID resource] WithPresence:[presence type]];
    }
}


- (void) requestAllMesssage
{

//    <presence
//    from='hag66@shakespeare.lit/pda'
//    id='n13mt3l'
//    to='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit/thirdwitch'>
//    <x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'>
//    <history since='1970-01-01T00:00:00Z'/>
//    </x>
//    </presence>
//    
//    NSXMLElement *iQ = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"presence"];
//    [iQ addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"get"];
//    [iQ addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:@"n13mt3l"];
//    
//    NSXMLElement *retrieve = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"retrieve"];
//    [retrieve addAttributeWithName:@"xmlns" stringValue:@"urn:xmpp:archive"];
//    [retrieve addAttributeWithName:@"history since" stringValue:@"1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"];
//    
//    NSXMLElement *set = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"set"];
//    [set addAttributeWithName:@"xmlns" stringValue:@"http://jabber.org/protocol/muc"];
//    
//    [retrieve addChild:set];
//    [iQ addChild:retrieve];
//    
//    [xmppStream sendElement:iQ];




}

- (void)xmppRoom:(XMPPRoom *)sender didFetchConfigurationForm:(NSXMLElement *)configForm
{
    DDLogInfo(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);

    NSXMLElement *newConfig = [configForm copy];
    NSArray *fields = [newConfig elementsForName:@"field"];

    for (NSXMLElement *field in fields)
    {
        NSString *var = [field attributeStringValueForName:@"var"];

        // Make Room Persistent
        if ([var isEqualToString:@"muc#roomconfig_persistentroom"])
        {

            [field removeChildAtIndex:0];
            [field addChild:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"value" stringValue:@"1"]];
        }

        if ([var isEqualToString:@"roomconfig_enablelogging"])
        {

            [field removeChildAtIndex:0];
            [field addChild:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"value" stringValue:@"1"]];
        }

        if ([var isEqualToString:@"muc#roomconfig_maxusers"])
        {

            [field removeChildAtIndex:0];
            [field addChild:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"value" stringValue:@"100"]];
        }


    }
    //    [sender configureRoomUsingOptions:newConfig];
}

/**
 This fuction is used to destroy created room
 */
- (void) destroyCreatedRoom
{
    [xmppRoom destroyRoom];

}


- (BOOL)sendGroupMessageWithBody:(NSString*)_body
{

    [xmppRoom sendMessageWithBody:_body];
    return YES;
}


@end
```